# MongoDb run command from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo query in string format. How can I run this string query on mongo?

I can run this on mongo shell:

```
db.getCollection('myCollenction').find({})
```

How can I run the same command on node.js mongo native driver?

```
var query = "db.getCollection('myCollenction').find({})";
db.runCommand(query);
```

I have a mongodb query builder and now I need to get the generated query and execute on mongo.

I'm using node.js 8.11.1 and mongodb native node driver 3.1

**Edit**

I found that I can run the mongodb **eval** funtion to do that, but it is deprecated. There's another way to do that? Or there's another way to get the generated condition on jquery-querybuilder and execute on my mongo database to get the results?

Comment: What is the query generated by?

Comment: I'm using jquery-querybuilder to build a mongodb query. The jquery-querybuilder generates an object array containing the mongodb conditions or the same object condition in a string json format. So I need get this "Object" or string and execute on my mongo databse to get the result.

Comment: You really should serialize the object, send the object to the server, then construct the query by traversing the object server-side after validating the object's schema. This will make your server much less vulnerable to attacks. You should never give clients the ability to send strings that are evaluated directly on the server.

Comment: Yes you are right. What about using eval? Is there another way to execute a command in Mongo?

Comment: Using [query and projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/), you can essentially get a 1-to-1 translation from querybuilder's output format to a query that can be passed directly to `collection.find()` using a recursive object transformation function. If no one gives you a satisfactory answer in the next few hours, I'll write an answer later to provide an implementation for the transformation function you can use for a subset of the querybuilder syntax that should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Wow, that's great. I'll wait for your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to notice that [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Specifications) is not "deprecated", but not recommended to prevent especially such case of use.

Comment: Mongodb database.eval() is deprecated since mongodb 3.0. [db.eval](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval)

Comment: Good point. My comment was more about the js `eval` than the mongodb wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [mongodb-support](https://querybuilder.js.org/plugins.html#mongodb-support) plugin that comes with jQuery QueryBuilder, you can use the `getMongo()` method to get an object that can be passed directly to [`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

```js
var rules_basic = {
  condition: 'AND',
  rules: [{
    id: 'price',
    operator: 'less',
    value: 10.25
  }, {
    condition: 'OR',
    rules: [{
      id: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 2
    }, {
      id: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 1
    }]
  }]
};

$('#builder-basic').queryBuilder({
  plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
  filters: [{
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    id: 'category',
    label: 'Category',
    type: 'integer',
    input: 'select',
    values: {
      1: 'Books',
      2: 'Movies',
      3: 'Music',
      4: 'Tools',
      5: 'Goodies',
      6: 'Clothes'
    },
    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
  }, {
    id: 'in_stock',
    label: 'In stock',
    type: 'integer',
    input: 'radio',
    values: {
      1: 'Yes',
      0: 'No'
    },
    operators: ['equal']
  }, {
    id: 'price',
    label: 'Price',
    type: 'double',
    validation: {
      min: 0,
      step: 0.01
    }
  }, {
    id: 'id',
    label: 'Identifier',
    type: 'string',
    placeholder: '____-____-____',
    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal'],
    validation: {
      format: /^.{4}-.{4}-.{4}$/
    }
  }],
  rules: rules_basic
});

$('.parse-json').on('click', function() {
  var result = $('#builder-basic').queryBuilder('getMongo');
  alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-PmY9l28YgO4JwMKbTvgaS7XNZJ30MK9FAZjjzXtlqyZCqBY6X6bXIkM++IkyinN+" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vhJnz1OVIdLktyixHY4Uk3OHEwdQqPppqYR8+5mjsauETgLOcEynD9oPHhhz18Nw" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="builder-basic"></div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary parse-json" data-target="basic">Get Query</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```